# Reinterpret C# raw buffer into a blittable structure

Tags: c#, pointers, unsafe, reinterpret-cast, stackalloc

I'm looking for a way to reinterpret an arbitrary unsafe memory region as a blittable structure in C#. Here is a failed attempt I could write so far:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = sizeof(int))]
struct Foo
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int X;
}

public static unsafe void Main()
{
    // Allocate the buffer
    byte* buffer = stackalloc byte[sizeof(Foo)];

    // A tentative of reinterpreting the buffer as the struct
    Foo foo1 = Unsafe.AsRef<Foo>(buffer);

    // Another tentative to reinterpret as the struct
    Foo foo2 = *(Foo*) buffer;

    // Get back the address of the struct
    void* p1 = &foo1;
    void* p2 = &foo2;

    Console.WriteLine(new IntPtr(buffer).ToString("X"));
    Console.WriteLine(new IntPtr(p1).ToString("X"));
    Console.WriteLine(new IntPtr(p2).ToString("X"));
}
```

Nevertheless, the printed memory addresses are all different (I expected the same address to be printed). The first attempt uses the `Unsafe.AsRef<T>(..)` provided by Microsoft, where the description of method says:

> Reinterprets the given location as a reference to a value of type `T`.

I'm not sure why the reinterpret is not properly done here.

Any advice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reinterpreting works as intended, the reason the addresses are different is that these two lines create independent copies of data in two new variables:

```
Foo foo1 = Unsafe.AsRef<Foo>(buffer);
// ...
Foo foo2 = *(Foo*) buffer;
```

To avoid the copying, you can declare the variables as `ref` locals (from C#7 onwards) or pointers:

```
byte* buffer = ...

// Option 1, pointers only
Foo* foo1 = (Foo*)buffer;
foo1->X = 123;

// Option 2, ref local cast from pointer    
ref Foo foo2 = ref *(Foo*)buffer;
foo2.X = 456;

// Option 3, ref local with Unsafe.AsRef
// Unlike option 2 this also allows reinterpreting non-blittable types,
// but in most cases that's probably undesirable
ref Foo foo3 = ref Unsafe.AsRef<Foo>(buffer);
foo3.X = 789;
```

Comment: Hey @kalimag, thanks for your great answer! Does it means that my tentatives were in fact copying the structures in memory, instead of referencing the buffer ? Your example using `ref` locals is great. Could you please add a second code snippet without the usage of `ref`locals for completeness, as I'm not sure what do you mean by *but then you dereference the `ref Foo/Foo*` and assign them to `foo1` and `foo2`* ? I do not immediately how I can solve that without the `ref` locals trick. Many thanks !

Comment: Yes, whenever you assign a `struct` to a new variable, the value is copied. If you want to avoid that copy, you need to refer to the original memory location with a `ref Foo` or `Foo*` and not assign it to a new variable of type `Foo`. I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to solve, but if you want to stick to pointers all you need is code like `Foo* foo = (Foo*)buffer; foo->X = 123;`

Comment: Yeah right ! This fully answer my question. Many thanks!